# Controlling an OceanOptics FLAME-S spectrometer by Python

Tags: python, usb

I am trying to communicate with an Ocean Optics FLAME-S spectrometer via Python. I read that Python Seabreeze package can be used for this purpose but apparently it seems to be not working for FLAME-S. I am very new to Python, so any lead is highly appreciated.

(Maybe calling the spectrometer by its serial number could work. But I don't know how to find the serial number by Python.)

The following code I wrote to find the serial number of the device. But all I get for the output is `[]`

```py
from seabreeze.spectrometers import list_devices, Spectrometer
devices = list_devices()
print(devices)
```

Answer (score 0):

In: `list_devices()`

Out: `[<SeaBreezeDevice USB2000PLUS:FLMS14964>]`

Must be the power or something else. This does work for FLAME-S spectrometer device.